# FirebaseFunctions.getinstance() not finishing

Tags: firebase, promise, task, google-cloud-functions

I am using FirebaseFunctions as well as https://github.com/voltrue2/in-app-purchase to validate purchases. I am having trouble sending the data back to my client. In the logs of my functions everything goes well and I get the result I want, but as I understand you have to return a promise in order to get the data back to the client when using Firebase's onCall https trigger. The code for my oncall trigger is here.

```
var iap = require('in-app-purchase');
var purchaseData;
const receipt = data;


iap.config({
    googlePublicKeyPath: 'acualpublickey' ,
    googleAccToken: 'actualtoken',
    googleRefToken: 'actualtoken', 
    googleClientID: 'actualID', 
    googleClientSecret: 'actual seceret', 




});


iap.setup()
        .then(() => {
            console.log("receipt: ", receipt)


            return iap.validate(receipt).then(onSuccess).catch(onError);





        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("error setup: " + error);
            throw error;
});




function onSuccess(validatedData) {

    var options = {
        ignoreExpired: true // purchaseData will NOT contain exipired subscription items
    };
    purchaseData = iap.getPurchaseData(validatedData, options);

    console.log("PurchseData : ", purchaseData);
    console.log("ValidatedData : ", validatedData);
    return purchaseData;
}


function onError(error) {
    console.log("error onError: " + error);
    throw error;
}
```

the function it is called on to be used is this one

```
 void receiptJSONvalidation(String receipt){
    if (receipt != null) {
        try {


            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(receipt);

            Task<Object> validatedReceipt =  validation(jsonObject);

            validatedReceipt.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Object> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Exception e = task.getException();
                        if (e instanceof FirebaseFunctionsException) {
                            FirebaseFunctionsException ffe = (FirebaseFunctionsException) e;
                            FirebaseFunctionsException.Code code = ffe.getCode();
                            Object details = ffe.getDetails();

                            errorAlert("task unsuccessful: " + details.toString());
                        } else {
                            errorAlert("Error onComplete: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }

                        // ...
                    } else{
                        Gson gson = new Gson();

                        String taskResult = gson.toJson(task.getResult());
                        errorAlert("taskResult: " + taskResult);
                    }
                }
            });


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            errorAlert("Error Json: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

    } else {
        errorAlert("You are not subscribed. Please purchase a subscription.");
    }
}
```

the validation method is this

```
private Task<Object> validation(JSONObject receipt){
    mFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance();
    return mFunctions.getHttpsCallable("receiptValidation").call(receipt)
            .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult,Object>() {
                public Object then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                    // This continuation runs on either success or failure, but if the task
                    // has failed then getResult() will throw an Exception which will be
                    // propagated down.
                    Object result = task.getResult().getData();

                    return result;
                }
            });
}
```

When I get to both taskResult and result I am getting null while my logs have the actual data I need. I tried to follow the documentation for these functions yet I still don't get what is needed. Also there seems to be a problem with my app not allowing the firebase function to finish. Sometimes the result pops up null before the function is even over. The function will say it took about 8 sec. Yet the alert pops up in way less time.

Comment: "... not allowing the firebase function to finish" is certainly consistent with not returning a required promise. From which function do you suspect a promise should be returned?

Comment: If I had to guess, it would be that `mFunctions.getHttpsCallable(...).call(...).continueWith()` needs to be promisified and that the promisification needs to include `result.addOnCompleteListener(...)`, from which you will resolve/reject a `new Promise()` wrapper (which is returned). Thus, much of the code currently in `receiptJSONvalidation()` will be shuffled into `validation()`, leaving behind code of the general form `return validation(jsonObject).then(...);`. You may still need the `if/try/catch/else` structure - just make sure all branches return Promise.